# When should one use a class method over instance method?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Though I read the definitions of class and instance methods, I'm unable to understand the right use case for each of them. It will be nice if someone can provide examples of when class methods are preferred over instance methods and the vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, Gerrat - I missed that question when I searched.

Comment: No worries! A recommendation would be to search Google for stackoverflow results as opposed to stackoverflow's own search feature - it is often better.